# Solidity - Mint with one contract from another contract

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to mint from contract A to contract B. But I am getting "Fail" error. I guess contract B is trying to send NFT to contract A but is unable to deliver. How can I fix this error? I was hoping NFT would go to msg.Sender. Thank you very much for your help.

````
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;


interface Ether {
function register(address ref_address, string memory ether_name) external payable;
}


contract Contract2{

address ether_contract=0xDC7dBb61E31D7a79376063791183A6488E16C9ce;

function transfer () public payable{}
    receive() external payable {}
    fallback() external payable {}

function register(string memory ether_name) public payable
{
Ether(ether_contract).register(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000,ether_name);
}


}```
````

Comment: Can you dig deeper and find the exact error it gives? One wrong thing I'm seeing is that you're not sending along any ETH to register, but maybe it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us the code or some more information about the register function? There could be some reverts in it that are not allowing you to proceed with the call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are encountering is likely caused by the fact that the NFT is being sent to the address specified in the register function, which is set to the zero address (0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000). To fix this, you should change the address passed to the register function to the address of the contract that should receive the NFT (in this case, contract A).